# firebase sessions cookies and storage rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I've noticed on the docs for [firebase session cookies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies) that it states:

> For security reasons, Firebase session cookies cannot be used with other Firebase services due to their custom validity period, which can be set to the maximum duration of 2 weeks. All applications using server side cookies are expected to enforce permissions checks after verifying these cookies server side.

Does this mean that I can't use the auth claims to specify security rules for cloud storage uploads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use auth claims in Cloud Storage security rules.  [Read the documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage/#properties).